# .bashrc PS1: \w for WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, bashrc

I'm using Debian on WSL. However I mostly work in the Windows path. Currently my `PS1` in `.bashrc` looks like this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

This makes the path very long when on the windows drive, because it always shows the unnessecary prefix `/mnt/c/Users/name`. I was wondering if there was a possibility to display the path relative to `/mnt/c/Users/name`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the path in `pwd` exactly match what you've put in $HOME (specifically, differences in upper/lower case)?

Comment: Somehow it works now using `$HOME`. Maybe I misconfigured something different or had a trailing `/`. But your answer is the better way for sure. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable can contain any shell expansion, as your own example shows; if the expansions are quoted/escaped to prevent their evaluation during assignment, they will be evaluated again every time the prompt is shown.

So instead of `\w`, you could use `$PWD` together with various string expansions to replace its prefix:

```
PS1='etc etc ${PWD/#"/mnt/c/Users/name/"/"Win/"} etc'
```

This would replace the prefix `/mnt/c/Users/name/` with `Win/`. (It's not ideal because it only works when the trailing slash is present, i.e. when you're in a subdirectory, but somehow it doesn't feel right to omit the trailing slash as that could result in weird collisions...)

You could even use function output:

```bash
fancyprompt() {
    local wd="$PWD/"
    wd=${wd/#"/mnt/c/Users/name/"/"W:/"}
    wd=${wd%"/"}
    wd=${wd//"/"/"\\"}
    echo "$wd"
}

PS1='etc etc $(fancyprompt) etc'
```

Note the single quotes `'...'` which prevent immediate $-expansion.

(You could even have the *entire* prompt be displayed by the function; if you decide to do so, make sure to output `\001` and `\002` around color codes instead of the `\[ \]`.)